# Excel - Office 365 formula loss on refresh

Tags: microsoft-excel-365

I have a query of external data, with a date range parameter. Included in the table are several columns which make calculations based on the queried data. My issue is when I change the dates or refresh the data, the formulas are erased. How can prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Power Query (Get & Transform), you can insert columns with calculations between query columns or at the end of the table. You only need to ensure that the table properties (Table Design > Properties) are set as follows:

[image]

I haven't tested with other query types, but this should preserve custom columns in other types, too.